# Functional rating in custom grid view using JSON formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, microsoft-lists

In SharePoint Lists you can add a fully functional rating column. With "functional" I mean that you can both see the ratings (value and stars) of every list item and you can click on a star to add your rating for that item. I marked with red in this picture what rating column I'm referring to.

[image: Native ratings in list view]

I would like to have the same functional rating embedded into a Grid view. I'm creating the Grid view using the JSON formatting option. This is what I currently created, I'd like to add those functional stars from the list view in the red marked part.

Grid view where I'd like to put the functional rating:

[image: Grid view where I'd like to put the functional rating]

Comment: Ratings showed in first image is SharePoint OOTB ratings? Or you have created that using JSON formatting?

Comment: Those are the OOTB ratings

Comment: You can try JSON sample given in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create star rating using JSON formatting in SharePoint online.

Check below JSON samples which provides similar functionality: [Star Rating](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/number-star-rating)

[image]

You can refer and use the part of this JSON in your view formatting JSON.

---

If you have created a custom JSON formatting for your column in list view, you can refer same JSON formatting in view formatting with simple JSON like:

```
{
  "columnFormatterReference": "[$FieldName]"
}
```

Where `FieldName` is the internal name of your Ratings column. Follow this article to find the internal name of your column: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Or you can use JSON in reference link for your Ratings column and then refer same JSON in grid view formatting using `columnFormatterReference` as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ganesh. With that sample you provided are users able to click the stars to give a rate? Reading its code I understand that it only displays the rating value, but have no way to vote a rate.

Comment: You can use `setValue` to update the likes count and users in LikedBy field. Refer this sample for the same: https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/generic-like-unlike

Comment: I didn't know about `setValue`, thank you, but the sample you provided manages Likes, but I need to work on Rating. Any user should be able to provide a rate (0-5) and the average of those is the value shown along with the stars. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In above link, I am using same logic for like/unlike. It shows total count of all like/unlike. In similar way, you can update SharePoint default LikesCount and LikedBy field using setValue on click of custom rating created using JSON.

Comment: Check this link as well for one more similar sample: https://github.com/Fedes365/Microsoft-Lists-Templates/wiki/Star-Rating:-a-new-way-to-rate-documents-and-info-with-Microsoft-Lists

Comment: I've been struggling with the same.  I don't think it is possible with the OOTB rating system, as it creates two columns that are hidden (`Ratings` and `RatedBy`)  I've been unable to use `setValue` to change either of these.  The second example @GaneshSanap-MVP gives is probably the best bet as it doesn't use the OOTB rating system but rather creates its own. See this question I asked: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/311125/change-rating-field-in-gallery-view-card?noredirect=1#comment328408_311125